# Call method of dynamic type, not static one

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    void m() {
        std::cout << "hi";
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void m() {
        std::cout << "hello";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A*> v;
    v.push_back(new A);
    v.push_back(new B);
    v.push_back(new A);
    for (A *obj : v)
        obj->m();
}
```

The problem is that this program prints `hihihi` instead of `hihellohi`, and it means that it always calls the `m()` method of the static type (i.e. `A`) rather than the dynamic one (`B`). How can we always call the `m()` method of the dynamic type?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then declare `virtual void m()`.

Comment: If you know about static vs dynamic types, surely you know about virtual functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base class function should be virtual in order to have polymorphic behaviour:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void m() {  // <-- You missed this virtual
        std::cout << "hi";
    }
};
```

and for derived class, it should be override:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    void m() override {
        std::cout << "hello";
    }
};
```